# UDF to extract String in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to extract the last set number from this data type:

```
urn:fb:candidateHiringState:(urn:fb:contract:187236028,10342800535)
```

In this example I'm trying to extract `10342800535` as a string.

This is my code in scala,

```
def extractNestedUrn(urn: String): String = {
    val arr = urn.split(":").map(_.trim)
    val nested = arr(3)
    val clean = nested.substring(1, nested.length -1)
    val subarr = clean.split(":").map(_.trim)
    val res = subarr(3)
    val out = res.split(",").map(_.trim)
    val fin = out(1)
    fin.toString
  }
```

This is run as an UDF and it throws the following error,

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason that `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function` exception are raised is when an exception is raised inside your user defined function.

### Analysis

If I try to run your user defined function with the example input you provided, using the code below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}
import sparkSession.implicits._

val dataframe = Seq("urn:fb:candidateHiringState:(urn:fb:contract:187236028,10342800535)").toDF("urn")

def extractNestedUrn(urn: String): String = {
  val arr = urn.split(":").map(_.trim)
  val nested = arr(3)
  val clean = nested.substring(1, nested.length -1)
  val subarr = clean.split(":").map(_.trim)
  val res = subarr(3)
  val out = res.split(",").map(_.trim)
  val fin = out(1)
  fin.toString
}

val extract_urn = udf(extractNestedUrn _)

dataframe.select(extract_urn(col("urn"))).show(false)
```

I get this complete stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(UdfExtractionError$$$Lambda$1165/1699756582: (string) => string)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1130)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:156)
  ...
  at UdfExtractionError$.main(UdfExtractionError.scala:37)
  at UdfExtractionError.main(UdfExtractionError.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
  at UdfExtractionError$.extractNestedUrn$1(UdfExtractionError.scala:29)
  at UdfExtractionError$.$anonfun$main$4(UdfExtractionError.scala:35)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2(ScalaUDF.scala:157)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1127)
  ... 86 more
```

The important part of this stack trace is actually:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

This is the exception raised when executing your user defined function code.if we analyse your function code, you split two times the input by `:`. **The result of the first split is actually this array:**

```
["urn", "fb", "candidateHiringState", "(urn", "fb", "contract", "187236028,10342800535)"]
```

and not this array:

```
["urn", "fb", "candidateHiringState", "(urn:fb:contract:187236028,10342800535)"]
```

So, if we execute the remaining statements of your function, you get:

```scala
val arr = ["urn", "fb", "candidateHiringState", "(urn", "fb", "contract", "187236028,10342800535)"]
val nested = "(urn"
val clean = "urn"
val subarr = ["urn"]
```

As at the next line you call the fourth element of the array `subarr` that contains only one element, an `ArrayOutOfBound` exception is raised and then Spark returns a `SparkException`

### Solution

Although the best solution to your problem is obviously the [previous answer with regexp_extract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64656295/6807769), you can correct your user defined function as below:

```scala
def extractNestedUrn(urn: String): String = {
  val arr = urn.split(':') // split using character instead of string regexp
  val nested = arr.last // get last element of array, here "187236028,10342800535)"
  val subarr = nested.split(',')
  val res = subarr.last // get last element, here "10342800535)"
  val out = res.init // take all the string except the last character, to remove ')'
  out // no need to use .toString as out is already a String
}
```

**However, as said before, the best solution is to use spark inner function `regexp_extract` as explained in [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64656295/6807769). Your code will be easier to understand and more performant**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use regexp_extract function. Check this

```
val df = Seq(("urn:fb:candidateHiringState:(urn:fb:contract:187236028,10342800535)")).toDF("x")

df.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|x                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|urn:fb:candidateHiringState:(urn:fb:contract:187236028,10342800535)|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

df.withColumn("NestedUrn", regexp_extract(col("x"), """.*,(\d+)""", 1)).show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|x                                                                  |NestedUrn  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|urn:fb:candidateHiringState:(urn:fb:contract:187236028,10342800535)|10342800535|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```